# Python template, is there a way to inherit from multiple html files?

Tags: python, templates, flask

So say that I have this structure

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>Here goes content 1</div>
      <div>Here goes content 2</div>
      <div>Here goes content 3</div>
   <body>
</html>
```

I can do an extends on another file, and instead of having Here goes content 1,2,3 I can have blocks. But that means whichever file inherits this base template, will have to have all three blocks in it. Is it possible to do something like

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>{% grabfrom 'firstdiv.html' %}</div>
      <div>{% grabfrom 'seconddiv.html' %}</div>
      <div>{% grabfrom 'lastdiv.html' %}</div>
   <body>
</html>
```

and then I can serve this template?

Comment: You mean by [including those blocks](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include)?

Comment: Ahh! It was include, I was looking for the wrong keyword. Thanks @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`{% include '<template name>' %}` syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) to load other templates into specific locations:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div>{% include 'firstdiv.html' %}</div>
      <div>{% include 'seconddiv.html' %}</div>
      <div>{% include 'lastdiv.html' %}</div>
   <body>
</html>
```

If those includes do not need access to the current context (variables), you can enable caching of those includes by adding the keywords `without context` to the statements:

```html
 <html>
   <body>
      <div>{% include 'firstdiv.html' without context %}</div>
      <div>{% include 'seconddiv.html' without context %}</div>
      <div>{% include 'lastdiv.html' without context %}</div>
   <body>
</html>
```

See the [*Import Context Behaviour* section](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-visibility) of the template designer documentation.